# Trac base URL not rewritten when deployed via htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, trac

**How do I convince trac to omit `trac.cgi` from its internal links?**

I have a trac instance deployed in a user directory using htaccess and mod_rewrite, and would like the URLs to be of the form `http://example.com/foo/ticket/1`. Editing the server config is not possible.

My user web directory contains

```
$ ls -A foo
.htaccess trac.cgi
```

.htaccess contains what is recommended [on the Trac website](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracPrettyUrls):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ trac.cgi/$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^$ trac.cgi [L]
```

This is partially successful, as I can go to `http://example.com/foo/ticket/1` and get the correct page. However, all links that Trac generates on its Wiki pages still include 'trac.cgi'. The page source trac generates has links like

```
<a href="/foo/trac.cgi/wiki/WikiStart">
```

I tried to find out how trac determines the base URL to use, but was unsuccessful.
Editing `trac.ini` with

```
base_url = http://example.com/foo/
use_base_url_for_redirect = true
```

had no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this is an open Trac issue ([Trac ticket 2299](http://trac.edgewall.org/ticket/2299)), and a workaround for now is to edit `trac.cgi` and add the line

```
 os.environ['SCRIPT_NAME'] = "/foo"
```

That fixed it for me.